# Threadpool executor not updating the concurrent hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, concurrenthashmap

I am spawning 5 threads using the thread pool executor to execute 5 different commands in parallel. After completion of each thread i am updating the concurrent hashmap with the entries of threadid as a key and terminated as value. But my threadpool is not updating the hashmap of the successful completion of the commands execution.

Main Class:

```
package com.cisco.executor;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainExecutor {

    static String element;
    static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
    static Integer array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
//  static Integer array[] = { 1 };
    static List<Integer> threadid = Arrays.asList(array);
    static String SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE");
    static String SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_CVDPRDLINE_DETAIL = ReadProperties.getInstance()
            .getProperty("SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_CVDPRDLINE_DETAIL");
    static String SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_INSTANCE_DETAIL = ReadProperties.getInstance()
            .getProperty("SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_INSTANCE_DETAIL");
    static String SQOOP_XXCCS_SCDC_PRODUCT_PROFILE = ReadProperties.getInstance()
            .getProperty("SQOOP_XXCCS_SCDC_PRODUCT_PROFILE");
    static String SQOOP_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B = ReadProperties.getInstance().getProperty("SQOOP_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executors = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
//      ThreadPoolExecutor executors = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        System.out.println("at executors step");
        List<String> getlist = getList();
        Iterator<Integer> itr2 = threadid.iterator();

        for (Iterator<String> itr = getlist.iterator(); itr.hasNext() && itr2.hasNext();) {
            String element = (String) itr.next();
            int thread_id = itr2.next();
            String[] command = { "ssh", "hddev-c01-edge-02", "\"" + element + "\"" };
            System.out.println("the command is as below ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
            System.out.println("inside the iterator");
            ParallelExecutor pe = new ParallelExecutor(command, thread_id, map);
            executors.execute(pe);
        }
        // executors.shutdown();
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: map.entrySet())
        {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();            
            System.out.println("The key is " + key + " The value is " + value);
            System.out.println("Thread " + key + " is terminated");
        }

    }

    public static List<String> getList() {
        List<String> commandlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("inside getList");
        commandlist.add(SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_SAHDR_CORE);
        commandlist.add(SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_CVDPRDLINE_DETAIL);
        commandlist.add(SQOOP_XXCCS_DS_INSTANCE_DETAIL);
        commandlist.add(SQOOP_XXCCS_SCDC_PRODUCT_PROFILE);
        commandlist.add(SQOOP_MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B);
        return commandlist;
    }

}
```

Runnable Class:

```
package com.cisco.executor;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ParallelExecutor implements Runnable {

    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ParallelExecutor.class);

    String[] command;
    int threadid;
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map;

    public ParallelExecutor(String[] command, int threadid, ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map) {
        this.command = command;
        this.threadid = threadid;
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProcessBuilder processbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        LOGGER.info(command);
        try {
            Process process = processbuilder.inheritIO().start();
            System.out.println("inside process builder ");
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String readline;
            while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                LOGGER.info(readline);
            }
            // getting the thread state and adding it to a collection
            Thread.State state = Thread.currentThread().getState();
            if (state == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
                map.put(threadid, "TERMINATED");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Is my implementation wrong. Can someone help me with the implementation.

Comment: When would you expect a thread to say it has TERMINATED?  If you were dead, would you be able to tell me you were dead?

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct. I missed that logic. So should i just capture the state and do an entry?

Comment: All i want to do is capture the thread id and the state after the execution of the thread and put it into the map for polling the map.

Comment: Suggestion: do not start with 5 threads. Start with code that doesn't use threads at all. If all of that works as expected; then turn the solution into something that uses 1 thread. If that works; then go for multiple threads. The point is: if you run into a problem; don't try to solve it within "the full puzzle"; instead try to reduce it to its absolute minimum. Besides: "map" is a pretty nothing-telling name for a variable. Try to use names in your code that really say what the "thingy" is used for. Especially for collections; maybe at some point, it is no longer a map, but something else.

Comment: Somewhat I believe you are misusing `ProcessBuilder`. Don't forget that if you want to, for instance, `ls "some file"`, the arguments to the constructor will be `"ls", "some file"`.

Comment: @Jägermeister i take your point. Thats a valuable one.

Comment: @dataEnthusiast you an only get the state after the execution of the thread, after the execution of the thread, not in the thread.  In any case, you don't need to because the thread should always terminate, so you can assume that is what happens.

Comment: @dataEnthusiast since you are using a thread pool, the thread don't die until you shutdown the thread pool.

Comment: Another hint: don't write code that uses static all over the place and a static main to test things. Instead: write unit tests. If you rethink your problem; you might be able to create abstractions that allow you to have full unit test coverage. Having "static" stuff; and using a static "main" for testing ... thats like 1999; not 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ThreadPoolExecutor does not terminate untill it is asked to do so.
So, first of all you have to call

```
// executors.shutdown();
```

, which you kept as commented.
2nd, you need to wait for the threads to terminate properly. for that add a loop, before for(Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet())

```
while (!es.isTerminated()) {
        }
```

But, since one thread will probably run many runnables and if I get you correctly you want to update the CHM once one Runnable is done with it's execution.

To do that, you have to use a CustomThread class. extends Thread
and override just 1 method, `afterExecute()` where from you need to put code to update CHM with Runnable 's id and terminated status. But remember this means completion of passed Runnables run() method, not the underlying Thread's termination.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to capture the outcome of a thread in the thread (which is error prone esp if an exception/error is thrown) I suggest you retain the Future objects and inspect those.

```
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    System.out.println("at executors step");
    Map<String, Future<?>> results = new HashMap<>();
    for (String element : getList()) {
        String[] command = { "ssh", "hddev-c01-edge-02", "\"" + element + "\"" };
        results.put(element, exec.submit(new ParallelExecutor(command, thread_id, map)));
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String, Future<?>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        try {
            entry.getValue().get();
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ " is complete");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ " failed with");
            e.getCause().printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @dataEnthusiast: As suggested by Peter Lawrey, retain Future Object and inspect the result. I too prefer same solution.